# Error while upgrading EXPO version from SDK 42 to 44

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I just tried to upgrade my expo app from SDK version 42 to version 44.  I did the following commands:

```
npm i -g expo-cli
expo upgrade
```

When I try to run npm install i get this:

```
The expo package was found in your package.json but we couldn't resolve the Expo SDK version. Run npm install and then try this command again.

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: expo-standard-web-crypto@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: expo-random@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-random
npm ERR!   expo-random@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional expo-random@"12.1.0" from expo-standard-web-crypto@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-standard-web-crypto
npm ERR!   expo-standard-web-crypto@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: expo-random@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-random
npm ERR!   peerOptional expo-random@"12.1.0" from expo-standard-web-crypto@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-standard-web-crypto
npm ERR!     expo-standard-web-crypto@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/michaelschmitz/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/michaelschmitz/.npm/_logs/2022-02-21T19_18_50_348Z-debug.log
```

I've never updated expo before and am unfamiliar with working with dependencies and package.jsons

here is my package.json as well:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "update-deps": "npm install -g npm && npm install -g expo-cli && npm install",
    "build-ios": "expo bi --release-channel beta -t archive",
    "build-android": "expo ba --release-channel beta -t app-bundle"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "5.0.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.1.4",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
    "expo-print": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-standard-web-crypto": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.15",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.16.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "^0.0.16",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-simple-time-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "expo-random": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "~17.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
    "jest-expo": "^44.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is in a react-native app and I was previously using version 42.

Answer (score 0):

From your error you should revert back to your last working Expo 42 commit.  Then do the following

```
npm uninstall expo-random
expo install expo-standard-web-crypto
```

The first will remove any direct dependency to expo-random from your package.json.

The second will reinstall `expo-standard-web-crypto` to the currently supported version for Expo 42.

Do you your test and commit if it works.

Then retry the update.

## General process

The general process I have when doing an upgrade is:

1. determine what direct dependencies are not needed by the app and uninstall them or move them to `devDependencies` if it should've been a dev dependency like jest, @types etc.
2. test to make sure app still works
3. attempt upgrade
4. note the errors and deal with the problematic dependencies

   - dealing with the problematic dependency may simply be updating the version of the dep, or
   - revendor the improper dependencies yourself since [it may take months for any fix to go through upstream](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4575),
   - change your code so you don't use it because [the upstream may no longer be maintained except by renovate bots](https://github.com/CareLuLu/react-native-web-jsonschema-form#readme)